# Check site inclusion and exclusion

Tags: java

I have two string variables `site_inclusion` and `site_exclusion`.  If `site_inclusion` has some values, then I don't care what values `site_exclusion` contains.  This means `site_inclusion` overrides `site_exclusion` if `site_inclusion` has some values. But if `site_inclusion` is null and `site_exclusion` has some values, then go into the `site_exclusion` loop.

Requirements:

1. If site_inclusion and site_exclusion both are null then set `useTheSynthesizer` as true;
2. If site_inclusion is not null and it matches with the `regexPattern` then set `useTheSynthesizer` as true. And I don't care what values are there in site_exclusion.
3. If `site_inclusion` is null and `site_exclusion` is not null and `site_exclusion` does not match the regexPattern, then set `useTheSynthesizer` to true.

I wrote the below code but somehow I think I am repeating some stuff here in the if/else loop. Any code improvements that fulfill my conditions will be appreciated.

```
String site_inclusion = metadata.getSiteInclusion();
String site_exclusion = metadata.getSiteExclusion();

// fix for redundant data per site issue
if(site_inclusion != null && site_inclusion.matches(regexPattern)) {
    useTheSynthesizer = true;
} else if(site_exclusion != null && !(site_exclusion.matches(regexPattern))) {
    useTheSynthesizer = true;
} else if(site_inclusion == null && site_exclusion == null ) {
    useTheSynthesizer = true;
}
```

Comment: Your [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940360/remove-repeated-code) should probably be merged into this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please spinning it to a separate function. Here is what I think is a little more simpler implementation.

```
public boolean checkInclusion(String site_i, String site_e, Regex re) {
    if (site_i != null)
        return site_e.matches(re);
    else if(site_e != null)
        return !site_e.matches(re)))
    else
        return true;
}
```

In your implementation, what happens when the site inclusion has values but does not match, and site_exclusion is null? It seems to not match any of the conditions, which is not in sync with the requirements from my reading.

Also what happens when the site inclusion has values but does not match, and site_exclusion has values that does not match? In your implementation, it seems like site exclusion takes precedence. But that does not seem to be the requirement.

Perhaps I am reading either requirement wrongly or your implementation conditions wrongly?

A rather terse implementation that is same as above is,

```
public boolean checkInclusion(String site_i, String site_e, Regex re) {
    if (site_i != null) return site_i.matches(re);
    return site_e == null || !site_e.matches(re)
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how OR works on return statement ?

Comment: It is just a return of a boolean value. So first site_e == null is evaluated. If it is true, then true is returned. If not, site_e.matches(re) is evaluated and its negation is returned.

Comment: The statement is same as [ bool x = site_e == null || !site_e.matches(re); return x; ]